# Linear programming, simplex method.

Tags: linear-programming, simplex-method

Why the requirement that variables must be non-negative isn't written in the corresponding tableau? Isn't this kind of constraint equivalent to others? For instance consider some LP with 2 variables $x_1 \geq 0, x_2 \geq 0$. I expect, that I can add two extra rows at the end of the tableau:
$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}... &1& 0& 0\end{array}\right]$ and $\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}... &0& 1& 0\end{array}\right]$. The reason that caused this question is that I obtain optimal value of LP with negative entries, but it must not by the condition of the exercise and I can't find another solution by the simplex method, only by selection, which isn't convenient.

UPD: I clarify a bit my problem. Firstly I mention, that I learn linear algebra and I encountered simplex method in context with linear algebra's methods, so my method of solving problem may differ a little bit from common. I have an optimization problem:
[image from textbook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdV4S.png)

I have put my problem into standard form (changed "=" constraint by two equivalent "<=" constraints and replaced minimize problem with maximize by multiplying objective function by -1):

- maximize subject to: -x1-2*x2  +x3

  ```
                     x2  -x3 <= 3
              2*x1+2*x2  -x3 <= 1
             -2*x1-2*x2  +x3 <= -1
                x1+2*x2+2*x3 <= 3
                x1,  x2,  x3 >= 0
  ```

Then, as I don't have starting feasible solution (0,0,0), I transform my problem: 1) max -x1-2*x2+x3 ---> max -y 2) I subtract "y" from each constrain that have negative right-side.

- maximize subject to: -y

  ```
                      x2  -x3    <= 3
               2*x1+2*x2  -x3    <= 1
              -2*x1-2*x2  +x3 -y <= -1
                 x1+2*x2+2*x3    <= 3
                 x1,  x2,  x3, y >= 0
  ```

This program have obvious feasible solution (0,0,0,1).
By pivoting on column of corresponding tableau I have found another solution (1,0,1,0) that gives me optimal value of "-y" equals 0, so I know that initial LP is feasible and at least have solution (1,0,1) (this answer is correct, but isn't supposed to be by the explanation from textbook).

Then I can pivot on columns of tableau corresponding initial LP.

\begin{array}{c|cccc|ccc|c}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & -1 & 0 \\
\hline
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -1 & 3 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 2 & -1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & -2 & -2 & 1 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 3 \\
\end{array}

\begin{array}{c|cccc|ccc|c}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & -3 & -3 \\
\hline
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -1 & 3 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & -2 & 0 & -2 & -5 & -5 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 2 & 5 & 5 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 3 \\
\end{array}

\begin{array}{c|cccc|ccc|c}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & -3 & -3 \\
\hline
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -1 & 3 \\
0 & 0 & -1/5 & 0 & 2/5 & 0 & 2/5 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1/5 & 2/5 & 0 & 2/5 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 3 \\
\end{array}

\begin{array}{c|cccc|ccc|c}
1 & 0 & -3/5 & 0 & 1/5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\hline
0 & 1 & -1/5 & 0 & 2/5 & 0 & 7/5 & 0 & 4 \\
0 & 0 & -1/5 & 0 & 2/5 & 0 & 2/5 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1/5 & 1/5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2/5 & 0 & 1/5 & 1 & 6/5 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}

From here you can see that (-17/7, 20/7, -1/7) is solution (optimal value -24/7), but contains negative entries. Correct answer written in textbook is (1,0,1) with optimal value 0. I suspect, that I have add x1,x2,x3 >= 0 constraints to tableau. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you explicit your problem and the steps you made? Did you use slack variables? You are not supposed to get negative variables with the revised simplex.

Comment: @caduk I have clarified my question.

Comment: After finding your feasible, you can't go back to your original tableau, as it is formulated for the point $(0, 0, 0)$. Instead, use the tableau calculated to obtain $(1, 0, 1, 0)$. Use the objective function $-x_1-2x_2 +x_3-y$ instead of just $-y$ (to keep updated your objective function with the change of basis), but only enter $y$ in the basis. You will get the same tableau and the same $(1, 0, 1, 0)$ solution, but now, your objective function is written in the new basis. Delete the column of $y$ column. You can now apply the classic simplex algorithm.

Comment: thanks @caduk, but when I should apply substitution of objective function by "-y" then? My textbook says, then if it is the case, that right-side contains negatives, I should substitute func by "-y".

Comment: If you want, you can use just $-y$ as an objective function, but you still need to update the original objective function when pivoting or recompute it in the new basis once you find a feasible solution.

Comment: Ok, as I understand, just writing tableau by constraints is corresponding to feasible vector (0,0,0). If I have another feasible vector, I have to recompute tableau. How do I do that? Don't my calculations represent recomputing tableau after finding feasible?

Comment: The tableau depends on a choice of basis, which, unless degeneracy, is uniquely determined by the current vertex of the polyhedra where we are. Variables are split between non basic variables (that are zeros) and basic variables. This dichotomy depends on the vertex where we are. The constraints and the objective function are at each step expressed as a linear expression of the non-basic variables. When we pivot, a non-basic variable become a basic variable and a basic variable become a non-basic variable so we have to pivot to re-express constraints in term of the new non-basic variables.